# Spring Security bcrypt encoding login is not working

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc, encryption, spring-security

My application is in hibernate and spring MVC. Previously log in used to work but now I implemented bcrypt encoding for password. after that nothing is working. I changed almost everything. Here I am giving you my code and config files. Please help me in finding out the problem.

app-security.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" 
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.2.xsd">

    <security:global-method-security secured-annotations="enabled" />

    <!-- These beans handle successful login and failure cases of login -->
    <bean id="myAuthenticationSuccessHandler" class="com.app.security.handler.MySimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler" />
    <bean id="myAuthenticationFailureHandler" class="com.app.security.handler.MySimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler" />

    <!-- Encrypter to encrypt password -->
    <bean id="encoder" class="org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder"/>

    <security:http auto-config="true"><!-- 
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/home*"    access="ROLE_USER" /> -->
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/admin"    access="ROLE_ADMIN" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/user"     access="ROLE_USER" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/group-admin"  access="ROLE_GROUP_ADMIN" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/sponsor"  access="ROLE_SPONSOR" />

        <security:form-login    login-page="/login" 
                                default-target-url="/home"
                                authentication-failure-handler-ref="myAuthenticationFailureHandler" 
                                authentication-success-handler-ref="myAuthenticationSuccessHandler"
        />
        <security:logout logout-success-url="/logout" />
    </security:http>

    <security:authentication-manager>
      <security:authentication-provider>
        <security:password-encoder ref="encoder" />
        <security:jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource"  
            users-by-username-query="select user_id as userId, username, password, email_address as emailAddress, active from users where username=?" 
            authorities-by-username-query="select us.user_id as userId, us.username as username, us.email_address as emailAddress, us.active as active, ur.roles from users us, user_roles ur 
              where us.role_id = ur.role_id and us.username =?  " 
        />
      </security:authentication-provider>
    </security:authentication-manager>

</beans>
```

UserService.java

```
@Service
public class UserService {

    @Autowired
    private UserDaoImpl userDaoImpl;
    @Autowired
    BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;
    /**
     * Save data in USER table
     * @param user
     */
    public void insert(User user) {
        //Encrypting password
        user.setPassword(passwordEncoder.encode(user.getPassword()));

        userDaoImpl.save(user);
    }
```

User.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name="USERS")
public class User implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 2158419746939747203L;

    @Id
    @Column(name="USER_ID")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long userId;

    @Column(name="USERNAME", unique = true, length=45, nullable=false)
    @NotEmpty @NotNull @Size(min=6, max=20)
    @UniqueCheck(classname="User", fieldname="username")
    private String username;

    @Column(name="PASSWORD", length=100, nullable=false)
    @NotEmpty @NotNull @Size(min=6, max=100)
    private String password;

    @Column(name="EMAIL_ADDRESS", unique = true, length=100, nullable=false)
    @UniqueCheck(classname="User", fieldname="emailAddress")
    @NotEmpty
    private String emailAddress;

    @Column(name="ACTIVE", nullable=false )
    private Integer active;

    @Column(name="ROLE_ID", nullable=false)
    private String roleid;
//getter setters
```

Let me know if any other info is needed

Comment: bcrypt is **not** encryption.

Comment: means BCryptPasswordEncoder class to encrypt

Comment: I will repeat what I said. bcrypt is **not** encryption.

Comment: sorry....encoding...am i right?

Comment: Not really. bcrypt is a [key derivation function](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt) which is used in this instance as a [cryptographic hash function](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function).

Comment: ohhkk..thanks.. this explanation is really good and helpful..I am reading it right now :)..but in my above code..am i missing any spring configuration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give strength to encoder in both the places (java file and xml config file)....it starts working.

So, 
*config.xml*

```
<bean 
id="encoder" class="org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder">        
        <constructor-arg value="12"></constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

*Service Layer Code:*

```
/**
     * Encoding data
     * bcrypt is a key derivation function which is used in this instance as a cryptographic hash function
     * @param data
     * @return
     */
    public static String bCrypt(String data) {
        BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder(12);
        return passwordEncoder.encode(data);
    }
```