# Spring Bcrypt not working

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Spring Bcrypt is not working in my Web Application. I've Spring 3.1.0 version in my application. Here I'm sharing some sample code what I tried.

```
BCryptPasswordEncoder encoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
System.out.println(encoder.matches(pwd, dbpwd));
```

It prints `false` even if I enter correct password. But some times if I enter wrong password it prints `true`. I'm saving encoding password in Database after encode

```
pwd = new BCryptPasswordEncoder().encode(pwd);
```

Why it's behaving in different ways. Am I missing anything here. Please correct me if I did wrong.

Comment: See this link.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28917254/spring-security-bcrypt-encoding-login-is-not-working

Comment: @AshwinGolani I've tried it. But its not working

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that your field in your database is not long enough.

You need at least a `CHAR(60) BINARY` or `BINARY(60)`, or you will lose data.

[Related post here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5882472/7709086)

Comment: Issue is not with size. I've column size of `60` in table. Still I'm unable to find what's the exact issue.